# change notification sound of ios(Flutter) using a network sound

Tags: ios, flutter, dart, alarm

using flutter my application users should be able to select notification sounds online dynamically, i am not able to find the solution for that, technology i am using is flutter

I have tried **local notifications** as well as different packages like ringtone. in android it is working smoothly but for iOS its not working. it gives an error

Comment: Search for audio playing packages and play audio when notification arrives. Also make sure to download the file user has selected and pass its file location to music player

Comment: i want to know that when you want to play notification sound when notification arrived or in application??

Comment: when notification arrived i tried everything but i think it doesnt work in latest android phones